# CSS- Float is disabling textbox in IE11 and Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

Im very new to CSS and web development.

For a simple form Im using CSS .float_left for textboxes. Second Textbox is working fine but the first text is getting auto disabled in IE11 and chrome but working fine in lower versions of IE(IE8).

Kindly help to enable the first textbox. TIA

Sample Code in JSP:

```
<div class="float_left" style="margin-right: 35px">
Phone Number:
<form:input path="phoneId" size="22" maxlength="8" htmlEscape="true"/>
</div>

<div class="float_left" >

<label>-or-</label>
<label>&nbsp;</label>
<label>&nbsp;</label>
</div>

 <div>
Email ID:
<form:input path="emailId" size="22" maxlength="4" htmlEscape="true" /> 
</div>
```

Sample Code in CSS

```
.float_left {
    float:left;
    *z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: why would you set your z-index to a negative value? Setting this to positive/0 should solve this.

Comment: found it via some blogs. what should be the exact method of setting?

Comment: You most likely don't need to do anything with it.

Comment: unless you're layering elements (which i don't believe you are), you should remove the declataion of it altogether.

Comment: In some cases it is pretty usefull to give a negative z-index, event though it's bad practice and you should try to avoid it.

Comment: @Doodlebunch: I'm not quite sure why you think it's bad practise... but again, z-index is useful for stacking/layering, not really for this purpose (which is, seemingly for 'no reason').

Comment: Negative value `z-index` is ***not*** bad practice. It's actually a very good practice when you understand what it does and need what it does. Consider animating an envelope shuffle effect without having negative `z-index` at your disposal. While still possible, it makes things a lot harder. Also, setting `z-index` to negative value behind a transparent parent is a very clean and reliable technique for avoiding double form submissions, without having to pollute the global object with a variable holding that information.

Answer (score 0):

Negative value for Z-index will hide the object so check it once by removing  that orelse try to give positive value 0.

Comment: Negative z-index values doesn't actually 'hide' the object. It places it behind the body element (so far as my understanding goes). So instead, you end up clicking on the body and not the input.

Comment: yea true I know it. Failed to express it properly.

Comment: Earlier I have used this property and have written a javascript function to display the object. Now I am confused whether it is helpful for this question or not?? @jbutler can u suggest??

Comment: z-index doesn't really hide or show elements, it sets their index/layer value. the display or opacity or visibility would be used to hide/show elements depending on what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: @jbutler483 It places it behind it's closest `position`-ed parent (other than `static`) with a set `z-index` (other than `auto`). If none, it places it behind the `<body>` indeed. Note that if that parent has `pointer-events:none` and the child being placed behind has `pointer-events:all`, the child receives pointer events. At priyanka. Your answer is incorrect. ***hide*** is quite inaccurate as to what's happening to that element. Also note that setting `z-index` on an element with `position:static` has no effect. Not specifying all these details lowers your answer's quality.